# Prove that if $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, $a>0$, then $\lim \frac{n^b}{(1+a)^n}=0$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

As the title says, i want to show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^b}{(1+a)^n}=0$$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a>0$.

I tried to bound the sequence $x_n =  \frac{n^b}{(1+a)^n}$ and use the sandwish theorem, but have no results. My problem is the exponent in the denominator, maybe it could be bounded with Bernoulli inequality ($(1+a)^n\geq 1+na$) but then the problem is de numerator $n^b$.

I'm grateful for any hints for doing this problem, or some steps to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Bernoulli's inequality won't suffice when $b\ge1$, but the binomial theorem will suffice.

From the binomial theorem, with $n>b$, we see that

$$(1+a)^n\ge \binom{n}{\lfloor b\rfloor +1}a^{\lfloor b \rfloor +1}$$

where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function.

Can you proceed?

Comment: Could you explain me more of your idea? I tried to use it to bound the sequence but i still don't see it. Thank you :)

Comment: Write out the term $\binom{n}{\lfloor b \rfloor +1}$.  Do you see that it is $O(n^{\lfloor b \rfloor +1})$

Answer (score 0):

We need to show that

$$\log\left(\frac{n^b}{(1+a)^n}\right)=b\log n-n\log(1+a)=n\left(b\frac{\log n}n-\log(1+a)\right) \to -\infty$$

that is

$$\frac{\log n}n \to 0$$

Comment: God dammit I was seconds away from posting.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Sorry! :)

Comment: @RushabhMehta Anyway in my opinion if your answer was near to be completed you could post it. I think it is not agains any rule and maybe your way to present things could be more clear to the asker or to other readers than mine.